# Rearrange values from different columns using bash / awk / perl / sed

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I have a file :

```
54      56        A
66      66        B
23       4        C
23      37        D
100     55        E
```

I would like to rearrange it so that colum 1 in always smaller or equal than column 2 :

```
54      56        A
66      66        B
4       23        C
23      37        D
55     100        E
```

I am interested in any short solution using `bash` / `perl` / `sed` / `awk`.

I made something in python with a `for` loop, checking for each line if col1 > col2, then writing a new file, but I have no clue how to do it more simply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '$2 < $1{n=$2; $2=$1; $1=n} 1' file

54      56        A
66      66        B
4       23        C
23      37        D
55      100       E
```

Answer (score 3):

As a Perl command-line program:

```
perl -a -n -E'say join "\t", sort({ $a <=> $b } @F[0, 1]), $F[2]' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you.

```
awk '{printf("%s\t%s\n",$1>$2?$2 "\t" $1:$1 "\t" $2,$3)}'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply using `printf` to print `awk`'s in-built command. Then inside it using `%s` 2 times with a TAB in them then `\n` new line at last to print next line on a new line. Now, while printing their respective values, I am using conditional operators `?` and `:` so checking condition here if first field is greater than 2nd field then print second field TAB and first field, if NOT then print vice versa of same.

Output will be as follows.

```
54      56      A
66      66      B
4       23      C
23      37      D
55      100     E
```

Comment: I hardly get an explanation from a down voter for down vote, which really discourages me :(